# How to call a C function from ASM in C?

Tags: c, function, assembly

I'm using this code but it gives me `Segmentation fault` when debugging. I'm compiling with MinGW:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int CallMe(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Called.");
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    printf("CallMe at 0x00%x\n", (unsigned int)&CallMe);
    printf("Calling CallMe... ");

    asm (
        "movl $5, (%eax);\r\n"
        "movl $4, (%ebx);\r\n"
        "call 0x00401334;\r\n"
    );

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The function address is ok. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try passing the -S option to the compiler to see what assembly is produced (the output will be a .s file). Compare this to when you try to call the function directly in C (without using the asm block). That should give you a good clue. If it doesn't, post both outputs here.

Comment: How yre you sure the "function address is okay?" First it's probably not okay, it might even change at runtime randomly if the OS uses address space layout randomization (ASLR).

Comment: @datenwolf, the code prints the function address. I assume that it prints the same address as per the call instruction.

Comment: @davmac: Well, the printf call is wrong actually. It should use the `%p` format and cast to `void*` to be useful. Also GCC inline assembly allows to use a symbol in the call instruction, avoiding the need for hardcoding alltogether.

Comment: why don't just call the function name?

Comment: @datenwolf - yes, it should really use `%p` but that hardly matters. The compiler is specified and the behavior of pointer-to-int conversion is documented for that compiler, so the code is "useful" as written. (And yes, the call could just use the symbol directly, but that doesn't answer the question that is being asked here.)

Comment: See mbratch's answer.  The two `movl` statements are pretty much guaranteed seg faults.

Comment: What is the purpose behind this coding exercise? Or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mbratch Just learning some ASM lol, my crazy projects :-P

Comment: I'm guessing that fixing the `movl` statements got rid of the seg fault, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is really executing in your `main()` function:

```
0x401268 <main>:    push   %ebp
0x401269 <main+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x40126b <main+3>:  sub    $0x8,%esp
0x40126e <main+6>:  call   0x401350 <__main>
0x401273 <main+11>: add    $0xfffffff8,%esp
0x401276 <main+14>: push   $0x401218  <--- address of CallMe
0x40127b <main+19>: push   $0x401242
0x401280 <main+24>: call   0x4013c0 <printf>
0x401285 <main+29>: add    $0x10,%esp
0x401288 <main+32>: add    $0xfffffff4,%esp
0x40128b <main+35>: push   $0x401250
0x401290 <main+40>: call   0x4013c0 <printf>
0x401295 <main+45>: add    $0x10,%esp
0x401298 <main+48>: movl   $0x5,(%eax)  <--- begin of your ASM block
0x40129e <main+54>: movl   $0x4,(%ebx)
0x4012a4 <main+60>: call   0x8024c1  <--- eewww! wrong address
```

So the question is now: why a `CALL 0x00401218` is assembled as `CALL 0x008024C1` ?

Of course, you will see also that parameters are not being passed by registers, but by pushing them into the stack.

In fact, I've got it by using this:

```
asm (
    "pushl $5;\r\n"
    "pushl $4;\r\n"
    "call _CallMe;\r\n"
    "addl %esp,$8;\r\n"
);
```

The problem I had before, about stack not bein balanced, was caused by a mistake in my code, that used `addl %esp,8` instead of `addl %esp,$8`. The former (tries to) add the contents of memory at address `8` to `ESP`, instead of adding the constant `8` to `ESP`.

If you want to collect the result of your function and save it, for example, in a variable, you can do as this:

```
int res;
...
...

asm (
    "pushl $5;\r\n"
    "pushl $4;\r\n"
    "call _CallMe;\r\n"
    "addl $8,%%esp;\r\n"
    "movl %%eax,%0;\r\n" : "=m" (res)
);
```

If you really want to call the function using its address, you can do it several ways:

By putting the address in a variable, say, a `void` pointer:

```
void *addr;

addr = (void *)CallMe;
asm (
    "pushl $5;\r\n"
    "pushl $4;\r\n"
    "calll *%1;\r\n"
    "addl $8,%%esp;\r\n"
    "movl %%eax,%0;\r\n" : "=m" (res) : "m" (addr)
);
```

Or by putting the address to call in a register:

```
asm (
    "pushl $5;\r\n"
    "pushl $4;\r\n"
    "movl $0x00401218,%%eax;\r\n"
    "calll *%%eax;\r\n"
    "addl $8,%%esp;\r\n"
    "movl %%eax,%0;\r\n" : "=m" (res)
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When trying to compile that I get `error: memory input 0 is not directly addressable`. Any ideas?

Comment: That works! Thanks. Now how can I call the function by it address?

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Also I was thinking how to read the return value, excelent! Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 4):

First problem is the call, as @EricZ points out.

However, fixing that won't necessarily make the segfault go away. Your two moves are also causing a problem:

```
movl $5, (%eax)
movl $4, (%ebx)
```

This is moving values `5` and `4` into locations whose addresses are in `%eax` and `%ebx`, respectively. In this particular program, those addresses haven't been defined. If you want to pass them as parameters, you need to push them onto the stack.

```
pushl $5
pushl $4
call CallMe     % With some compilers, this may need to be _CallMe
addl  $8,%esp   % assuming a 32-bit processor
```

Or, if the function expects them in the registers (I'm not saying it would in this case, but *if*...), remove the parentheses:

```
movl $5, %eax
movl $4, %ebx
```

You might want to read up on calling conventions, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I can't compile that, please see the comment above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753444/how-to-call-a-c-function-from-asm-in-c?noredirect=1#comment31101589_20753509). Also, which would be the solution for a 64-bit processor?

Comment: You need to put it in the same format as your `asm` statements. I was showing it as straight ASM for clarity, not intended for a simple copy/paste. I think you can do that bit of "translation" work. :) For 64-bit processors, the `push` might push an 8-byte value, in which case the stack adjustment would be `addl $16, %esp`.

Comment: @cdonts What you have there, using my suggestions, compiles fine and runs without a segmentation fault.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, if the space for the arguments is already been created, then following can be done:

`movl $4, (%esp)`
`movl $5, 4(%esp)`
`call <address>`

Comment: @mbratch It doesn't works for me, it doesn't compile. I'm using MinGW any ideas?

Comment: @cdonts, I'm using `gcc`. If you could indicate what your compile error message is and what line it's complaining about, that would help. If the problem is with the `call CallMe`, you could try `call _CallMe` to see if that works. I don't know what syntax `MinGW` is after. The important point of my answer is that the parameters must be set properly to avoid the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, don't call the function by its hard-coded address. Try call the function name instead. Function name is effectively the function address.

```
call 0x00401334
```

==>

```
call CallMe
```

Comment: This is only because C doesn't mangle the linker names, hence when the linker see's "CallMe" it knows what function it is supposed to be. Note that you can't do this in C++ as the function names don't always match the one's you used (its possible they might depending on the compiler).

Comment: While this is a worthwhile suggestion, it is not actually an answer to the question posed, and should have been made as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using `call CallMe` gives me an `undefined reference to CallMe` when compiling. Anyway, I need to call the function by it address, not the name.